# WebDAV through Apache2 permissions/missing files

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, webdav, debian-lenny

I have a WebDAV setup on Apache2 on a server running Debian 5.0 (Lenny), which I am accessing through a mapped network drive under Windows 7.

The setup appears to run fine, I receive no permission errors when copying a file to the share the first time, but the file never shows up in the directory (it's invisible, doing a ls -lha on the directory as root on the server also shows no files.

When attempting to copy the file once more I am informed that the file already exists though, and I am asked if I wish to overwrite the file, when selecting "Yes" to this, I receive a permission error saying I'm not able to write to the folder.

My logs aren't reporting any access violations of any kind, what could be the problem? (See log excerpt below)

> [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "PUT /1.png HTTP/1.1" 401 525 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "PUT /1.png HTTP/1.1" 201 304 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "LOCK /1.png HTTP/1.1" 401 525 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "LOCK /1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 447 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "PROPPATCH /1.png HTTP/1.1" 401 525 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "PROPPATCH /1.png HTTP/1.1" 207 389 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "HEAD /1.png HTTP/1.1" 401 - "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "HEAD /1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:34 +0100] "PUT /1.png HTTP/1.1" 401 525 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:35 +0100] "PUT /1.png HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:35 +0100] "PROPPATCH /1.png HTTP/1.1" 401 525 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:35 +0100] "PROPPATCH /1.png HTTP/1.1" 207 389 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:35 +0100] "UNLOCK /1.png HTTP/1.1" 401 525 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:35 +0100] "UNLOCK /1.png HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:38 +0100] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 401 525 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
>   [17/Jan/2011:10:26:38 +0100] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 207 1634 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV is using the path "/", where it should be using "/**User**".

Editing the apache VirtualHost to use **Location /*User* /path/to/*User***, and using a my.host.com/**User** as the mapped network drive address solved this issue.